# How map struct fields to columns in go-pg?

Tags: go-pg

I have some table in Postgres db and model in program

```
type Person struct {
   ID string
   Name string
   Addr Addr
}

type Addr struct {
  City string
  Street string
}
```

How specify map "Add" field in Person struct to PersonTable in db?

```
PersonTable
  id
  name
  addr_city
  add_street
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?